# Simple Calculator Not working

Tags: java, android, listener

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the following listener? I'm always crashing...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Editable num1 = NumberOne.getText();
    Editable num2 = NumberTwo.getText();
    int um1 = Integer.parseInt(num1.toString());
    int um2 = Integer.parseInt(num2.toString());
    Results.setText(um1 + um2);
}
```

Comment: What error messages are you seeing?

Comment: nothin, im just crashing on my phone

Comment: Hard to say without a stacktrace and this horrible variable naming. But i bet : Results.setText(String.valueOf(um1 + um2)); will fix it ;)

Comment: yeah that's fixed, Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setText method accepts a String as an argument. The result of um1 + um2 is going to be integer. I'd suggest you first convert the result to a String and then set it inside the setText method.

Something like this should work:

```
Results.setText(Integer.toString(um1+um2));
```

Even better you can do this:

```
Results.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(num1.toString()) + Integer.parseInt(num2.toString())));
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it is not working is because you cannot set text to an. You have to use `Results.setText(String.valueOf(um1 + um2))` (as Andre stated) to convert the integers to strings. Therefore, the setText will work.